# Handle PDF response in using RX and retrofit Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit "2.3.0" and rxJava2 = "2.1.1".
I'm not familiar with PDF responses.

I'm getting the response like this:

[image]

In my API how should I receive it? as a String?
I Think I should store it in a response JSON or somewhere to download it later from my presenter, right?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

PDF is a binary format, trying to manipulate it as a string does not work because a string implies it is encoded text. The subsequent decoding and encoding your software might do messes up the file and you get the result you are seeing.

You need to either use a binary format like a `ByteBuffer` or even a plain `byte[]`. Or leverage Retrofit's dependency on Okhttp and use `ResponseBody`'s `BufferedSource` directly.